# Arduino upload to Mega256 fails

Tags: upload, ide, arduino

I got the [SainSmart Mega2560 LCD Keypad Shield Sarter Kit](http://www.ebay.de/itm/SainSmart/320963105906) and want to upload the demo program for this LCD keypad. The IDE runs under Win7 x64 and the driver is correctly installed, I think.

I only get error messages

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): failed miserably to execute command 0x10
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

How can I check, if the connection really exists? Are there any know issues?

Comment: Have you tried googling these messages? Or maybe you haven't selected the correct Arduino model in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that many users have the same problem. My solution was now, that I removed the LCD Panel and the upload worked.

Comment: Yeah, it interfere with the serial pins which must be left unconnected when uploading the sketches. You can connect the LCD panel when upload is complete.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange problem, I encountered this problem when I attempted to connect IO expansion shield with Arduino 2560. I have tried many things but it didn't work. After many attempts I removed IO expansion shield from Arduino and then upload, It was worked. There is no clue why it can't upload when IO expansion shield is plugged. So this is a workaround solution but it is working. It is enough for me now.

--- FIXED ---
The problem has been fixed by checking all wiring on RS-485 network. GND and Termination wiring was missing after set these wiring properly the problem was fixed automatically. If you have this problem, I suggest that checking wiring once again.